# Watson deployment on Slack

Tags: deployment, ibm-watson, slack-api

Hi I'm trying to connect watson with slack. I followed all steps set out on the IBM deployment page and the video https://developer.ibm.com/videos/integrating-watson-assistant-with-slack-using-built-in-integrations/.

Everything is successful, but the bot is not responding when I'm writing a message to the slack app. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any conversation logs on the Watson Assistant side? If you're using Slack in the browser, can you open the console and see if any errors are shown?

Comment: Please do not re-post the same question, just because you did not get any answers on the first one. I will add better tags to your first question to help you get more attention. Also I would appreciate if you could remove this duplicate. Here is the other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53979864/integration-of-watson-to-slack-chat

Comment: Hi, I cannot see any conversiation logs on the watson assistant side. There is also no error in the slack console.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. When you go through the step-by step guide under STEP 3 IBM creates an URL. If the bot is hosted by IBM in London or Sydney, in the link you must replace the "eu-gb" (if London) or au-syd (if Sydney) reference in the URL with "us-south".

Afterwods the integration works. Further information can be found here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/deploy-web-link.html#deploy-web-link